# video not displaying on the the vfpage

Tags: visualforce, video

Video not display on the page

```
    <apex:page docType="html-5.0">
      <head>
          <script src="//api.html5media.info/1.1.8/html5media.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <video width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true">
              <source src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Video,'sample.mp4')}" type="video/mp4" />   


          Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video> 
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please provide your browser name and version.

Comment: Google Chrome
Version 48.0.2564.97 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:iframe scrolling="true" frameborder="true" src="{!URLFor($Resource.videotest,'VideoTest.mp4'}"/>
</apex:page>
```

It is working fine for me